# How to interact with 2 HTML document inside a single website?

Tags: html, excel, vba

Here's the main URL:
[image: Here's the main URL]

Main HTML Document:
[image: Main HTML Document]

the URL for the button i'm trying to locate:
[image: the URL for the button i'm trying to locate]

2nd HTML Document that I'm trying to get its handle:
[image: 2nd HTML Document that I'm trying to get its handle]

What I'm trying to do is get the handle of the button that I'm trying to click. However there are two URLs 1st is the main URL which is in the window and 2nd is the URL inside the window (when you right click > Properies the button the URL is different from the main Windows'). Also it is different or 2nd HTML Document (note: there's no iframe/frame.)

Only the 2nd URL that is I cannot get the handle in order for me to control its elements.

I already tried some codes below to get all handles.

```
    ConnectURL "Secondary URL"
    GetTheWindowHandle "IEFrame", "Secondary URL - Internet Explorer", hwndp
    SetForegroundWindow hwndp

    Sub ConnectURL(strURL As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sws = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows       
    jar = sws.Count - 1
    If jar < 0 Then
        MsgBox "There's no active IE or window Explorer", vbInformation, "Pop-out"
        Set sws = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    n = 0
    Do Until (n > 5000)
        If (Left(sws.Item(n).LocationURL, Len(strURL)) = strURL) Then
            If err.Number = 0 Then
                Exit Do 
            End If
            err.Clear
        End If
    
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Set ieDoc = sws.Item(n).document
    sws.Item(n).Visible = True
    Set ieLoad = sws.Item(n)
    End Sub
    
    Function GetTheWindowHandle(C`enter code here`lassName As String, toSearch As String, handle As Long)
    
    'Get Handle of window
        tempHandle = 0
        tempHandle = FindWindowEx(0, tempHandle, ClassName, vbNullString)
        
        Do While tempHandle <> 0 'while handle is not seen
        
            GetNameOfWindowByHandle tempHandle
            
                If InStr(1, TextResult, toSearch) > 0 Then 'Check if Window title is similar
                    handle = tempHandle 'capture handle
                    Exit Do
                End If
            
            tempHandle = FindWindowEx(0, tempHandle, ClassName, vbNullString)
            
        Loop
    End Function
    
    Function GetNameOfWindowByHandle(myHwnd As Long)
    'capture the title of the window
        Dim sbuffer As Long
        Dim lresult As String
        
        sbuffer = SendMessage(myHwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, vbNullString)
        sbuffer = sbuffer + 1
        TextResult = Space$(sbuffer)
        lresult = SendMessage(myHwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sbuffer, ByVal TextResult)
    
    End Function
    
    Example below
    <div class="slit-item-active" id="reportsTab" onclick="openReportExplorer();"><div class="nav-icon3"></div><span id="reportsTabText">Reports</span></div>
    
    this html code is on the button with the 2nd URL that I'm trying to get it's handle so i can use my code:
    
    iedoc.getelementbyid("reportsTab").click
    
    or
    
            waiting = 0
            Do While waiting = 0
                For Each obj1 In ieDoc.getElementById("reportsTab").getElementsByTagName("span")
                Debug.Print obj1.innerText
                    If Trim(obj1.innerText) = "Reports" Then
                        obj1.Click
                        ieLoading 2000
                        waiting = 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Loop
```

Comment: why can't you automate opening a browser with the first url and extract the second url from that page and pass to .Navigate2? I'm guessing this is not a public url?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the 2 HTML Documents that I'm trying to say, and I can't open it on another tab cause it will result an error page.

Comment: Are you saying that window pops up and you have to click the ok button?

Comment: no sir, not a pop up window, when I click the reports button that is on the it will show another menu which contains reports and when you click one of the link then the body will change depending on that and give results. the problem is, I couldn't get the 2nd HTML document in order for me to control that Reports Button on the 3rd image I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The click Event does not apply to this Div element/tag. You need to fire the onclick event instead.

`iedoc.getelementbyid("reportsTab").FireEvent "onclick"`

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I could do that if my iedoc is reading the HTML document where that element id is. but my iedoc reads the 1st HTML document... ahm I've added screenshot for you guys to see what I'm trying to say.